# `runBlocking` coroutine builder is not resolved in the project (Other builders are resolved)

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

As the title suggest, the coroutine builder `runBlocking` is missing in the coroutine liblary I just added in my build.gradle. Funny thing is every other thing appears to be available, `GlobalScope`, `CoroutineScope.launch` `CoroutineScope.async` all present. `runBlocking` isn't. What am I doing wrong?

here is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ktor_version = "1.1.1"
        kotlin_version = "1.3.20-eap-52"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-frontend-plugin:0.0.44"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.20-eap-100'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-js-wrappers' }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlinx/kotlinx' }
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

group 'books'
version '0.0.0'

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend"

kotlin {
    jvm() {
        compilations.all {
            tasks[compileKotlinTaskName].kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    js() {
        compilations.all {
            tasks[compileKotlinTaskName].kotlinOptions {
                def optDir = compileKotlinTaskName.contains("Test") ? "test/${project.name}.test.js" : "main/${project.name}.js"
                kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
                kotlinOptions.outputFile = "$project.buildDir.path/js/$optDir"
                kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
                kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'commonjs'
                kotlinOptions.main = "call"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$ktor_version"
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependsOn commonMain
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$ktor_version"
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-jdk8')
            }
        }
        jvmTest {
            dependsOn jvmMain
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test')
                implementation kotlin('test-junit')
            }
        }
        jsMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-js:$ktor_version"
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-js')
            }
        }
        jsTest {
            dependsOn jsMain
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-js')
            }
        }
    }
}

task runJest(type: Exec) {
    group = "verification"
    commandLine "sh", "runJest.sh"
}

runJest.dependsOn(jsTest)

task testAll() {
    group = "verification"
    dependsOn(jvmTest, runJest)
}

kotlinFrontend {
    npm {
        devDependency("karma")
    }

    sourceMaps = true

    webpackBundle {
        bundleName = "main"
        host = "0.0.0.0"
        contentPath = file("$buildDir.path/resources/main")
    }
}
```

With that gradle configuration, I have been able to write tests well (Learning TDD) with kotlin-multiplatform. And here is my sample below

```
import kotlin.test.*
import com.luge.books.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class BookTest {
    @BeforeTest
    fun setup() {
        val book = Book()
    }

    @Test
    fun testingInstantiation() {
        val book = Book()
        assertEquals(book.year, 1990, "Books do match the year")
    }

    @Test
    fun willFail() {
        assertFalse(false)
    }

    @Test
    fun testingCoroutines() {
        val job = GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(5000)
            println("Doing stuff")
            assertTrue(false)
        }
    }
}
```

If you look closely, the test `testingCoroutines` passes, but since I am launching from the `GlobalScope`, it just fires and forgets and the test returns without throwing any error. If I incoporate `runBlocking`, the IDE highlights it with red color (you know, as something it doesn't understant), end even the kotlin compiler shouts, `unresolved reference runBlockin`. Help please....

Comment: can you provide an example of your failing code

Comment: If I change the code in `willFail` test (See above) to `assertFalse(true)` it fails

Comment: obviously, but how does this test help?

Comment: It is meant to be a sample test. I do TDD, and need I remind that my query i with coroutines and not testing, I have no problem there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After struggling here and there, I finally knew that runBlocking is only available in kotlin/jvm. So, it is not in kotlin/js or kotlin/common.

Just for future references, if you want to run multiplatform tests, then use this [work around](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22228)

Comment: Since coroutines version 1.6.0 you can use `runTest()` method, which is a multiplatform replacement of `runBlocking` with some improvements. See [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/introducing-kotlinx-coroutines-1-6-0/#kotlinx-coroutines-test-update) jetbrains post.