# How to make a delay in Kotlin Multiplatform (pure kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Is there an equivalent to JVM's Thread.sleep() in pure Kotlin for use on MPP projects?  This could be implemented on each platform using `expected`, but I am asking about a solution that does not use that method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using coroutines.

For example:

```
runBlocking {
    println("Wait for 5sec")
    delay(5000)
    println("Done waiting for 5sec")
}
```

Comment: runBlocking is only available in kotlin/jvm - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54941299/1749806