# Execute code after 2 seconds in pure Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I need to execute some code after two seconds of waiting (without blocking the UI thread). The problem is that this is usually resolved with Timer or Handler but my app is using Kotlin Multiplatform, so I need it to be just pure Kotlin, not any Java library.

I would also need to be able to cancel the timer if I want to.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223336/how-to-make-a-delay-in-kotlin-multiplatform-pure-kotlin) asking more or less the same but they solve it using:

```
runBlocking {
    println("Wait for 5sec")
    delay(5000)
    println("Done waiting for 5sec")
}
```

But I don't really know how to cancel it and also if this is blocking the rest of the app.

Comment: You're almost done, instead of runBlocking just launch it into some dispatcher like Dispatchers.Main or Dispatchers.Default. It will not gonna block anything.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu and would that be cancelable also?

Comment: Yep! A coroutine by itself is cancellable unless it blocks something, in case of launch{} it is not going to block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get a `Job` reference when launching coroutine. You could do something like this:

```
    val job = coroutineScope.launch {
        delay(1000)
        doYourStuff()
    }
```

After thay you can use `job.cancel()`, or what ever you need. Also, you can define coroutine scope like this.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
```

Or any other dispatcher that suits your needs.
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

As a slight variation on the answer of @SamirSpahic, define a utility function

```
/**
 * Run [runnable] on the main dispatcher after an [interval] given in ms.
 */
fun runOnMainAfter(interval: Long, runnable: () -> Unit): Job {
    return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        delay(interval)
        runnable()
    }
}
```

then call it like this:

```
val job = runOnMainAfter(2000) {
    println("This executes after two seconds.")
}
```

It is almost a drop-in replacement for Handler.postDelayed(), with the arguments reversed.

The job can be cancelled with `job.cancel().`